# Task result to a file

Tags: ansible-tower

I have a simple playbook that run Cisco nxos command, which the playbook ran successful.
Would like to know what is the code save all the result into a file regardless how many hosts I have and use Survey to input the filename.

Currently, here is my code:

```
---

- name: run multiple commands on remote nodes
  nxos_command:
    commands:
      - show clock
      - show int status
      - show cdp neigh
      - show int desc
      - show port-channel summ
      - show vpc
      - show vpc role
```

**Try with code**

```
---

- name: run multiple commands on remote nodes
register: myshell_output

nxos_command:
 commands:
   - show clock
   - show int status
   - show cdp neigh
   - show int desc
   - show port-channel summ
   - show vpc
   - show vpc role
   

   - name: Saving data to local file
     copy:
       content: "{{ myshell_output.stdout|join('\n') }}"
       dest: "/tmp/hello.txt"
     delegate_to: localhost
```

**It give me an error:**

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_1869_7__9l_9l/project/roles/bcpcommands/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: run multiple commands on remote nodes\n  ^ here\n"}
```

The host normally I limit it at Ansible-Tower LIMIT column.
The ideal output of the file possible to include the hostname and commands that I key in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably got the indenting wrong. Try;

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - name: run multiple commands on remote nodes
      nxos_command:
        commands: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - show clock
        - show int status
        - show cdp neigh
        - show int desc
        - show port-channel summ
        - show vpc
        - show vpc role
      register: myshell_output

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ myshell_output }}"

    - name: Saving data to local file and include hostname
      copy:
        content: "{{ myshell_output.stdout|join('\n') }} hostname: {{ inventory_hostname }}"
        dest: "/tmp/hello.txt"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Edit the hostname.

The debug task must output an 'stdout' message. If that one is not present, then your copy task will fail.

Comment: Is the hostname refer to the devices? 
If my hostname is select frm the Limit column, how should I change the code. Without changing the hostname, it return : fatal: [router1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/project/roles/bcpcommands/tasks/main.yml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Saving data to local file and include hostname\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: Yes, change "my_host' to the respective hostname(s). Then look at the output of the debug msg. There must be an stdout message in there in order to make the task "Saving data to local file and include hostname" work.